# N-Best support for pocketsphinx Android!

Tags: android, android-ndk, sphinx, swig, speech-recognition

I have a research project in which i need n-best support in pocketsphinx android. I am using swig command line tool to generate pocketsphinx_wrap.c , and then NDK-build to generate shared library for android. The only problem is writing n-best content required in the pocketsphinx.i. Can any one please advise or guide me how to write function in pocketsphinx.i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't write the function but you write wrapper, it's a very different thing. We already discussed with you that in the forum thread here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/forums/forum/5471/topic/4566470

The wrapper should look like this:

```
typedef struct ps_nbest_s NBest;

typedef struct ps_nbest_t {
} Nbest;

%extend Nbest {
    Nbest(Decoder *d) {
        Nbest *nbest = ps_nbest(d, 0, -1, NULL, NULL);
        return nbest;
    }
    ~Nbest() {
        ps_nbest_free($self);
    }

    void next() {
        ps_nbest_next($self);
    }

    Hypothesis* hyp() {
        const char* hyp;
        int32 score;
        hyp = ps_nbest_hyp($self, &score);
        return new_Hypothesis(hyp, "", score);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you nikolay, I just made a few basic changes in the function provided and it worked, thanks once again!